# remote desktop using c#

Tags: c#

I'm developing a remote desktop application in C#.  I have client and server, and the server sends screenshots to the client & the client sends events.  I have done this , but the problem is when I send the click message, I don't know how to execute it on the server.

#### Update:

Now I'd like to send keyboard events from client to server, and the server should execute it.  Is there a function like ( mouse_event )?

Comment: We're going to need a little bit more information than that.

Comment: Please elaborate a little bit more and give some sample code.

Answer (score 3):

[This thread](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=321029) has some example code for generating mouse clicks:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Form1 : Form
{
   [DllImport("user32.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
   public static extern void mouse_event(long dwFlags, long dx, long dy, long cButtons, long dwExtraInfo);

   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

   public Form1()
   {
   }

   public void DoMouseClick()
   {
      //Call the imported function with the cursor's current position
      int X = Cursor.Position.X;
      int Y = Cursor.Position.Y;
      mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
   }

   //...other code needed for the application
}
```